# How to pass password using -S (stdin) in terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, stdin

i am trying to pass the password using `stdin` but I am getting an error.
Here is what I tried.

```
echo myPassword | sudo -S su - userName -s /bin/bash

echo 'myPassword' | sudo -S su - userName -s /bin/bash
```

In both case is am getting the error  of `-bash: line 1: myPassword: command not found`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: In general, this is a Very Bad Idea, and as someone who wears a security hat, I'd be putting anyone who checked it into a codebase I'm responsible for down for more training. You don't pass passwords in streams that are used for more than one thing, _especially_ when `sudo` might not need a password at all, depending on `/etc/sudoers` content.

Comment: Also, `sudo su` is itself an antipattern. `sudo` can do everything `su` can; you never need both at once, so anyone who's using them together is clearly parroting things they saw someone else do and never actually read `sudo`'s documentation. (See `sudo -i` and `sudo -l` re: making sudo start an interactive or login shell, and `sudo -u` to tell sudo to start a target shell as a chosen user).

Answer (score 1):

tricking a plaintext password into an ssh-based or other security relevant systems (also valid for SUDO, SFTP and likewise) is VERY difficult if it is designed to run in background because all above efforts will fail as soon as the terminal is gone.

The only way to safely fake the pwd entry requires deep knowledge of system calls to fake the input into an artifically added terminal (by e.g. `ssh -t´').

The **recommended way** to do non-interactive authentication with these things for remote access is the **private/public key authentication**. Using this, you are done within minutes. Trying to go the above way, you are an expert if you manage to get it done within a day. I intended to post my old solution for this, but I'm still searching that old code on my disk ... will post when found, but recommending not to use it.

The **recommended way** to deal with **sudo** without interactive password is the **NOPASS** option in sudoers.

Last but not least: the recommended way to switch to any user would be to have a sudo entry with root access to execute `su´ which is a security hoarse when equiped with NOPASS

Answer (score 0):

In your case you use an echo command instead of 'sudo' that's why error occurred.
you can use this command:

```
 sudo -S <<< "myPassword" su - userName -s /bin/bash
```

Alternatively, you can use the printf command to pass the password:

```
printf "myPassword\n" | sudo -S su - userName -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: the solution didn't work.

Comment: From the shell's perspective, `sudo -S su - username -s /bin/bash` is all one command and has its stdin set up only once; that's why `<<<"myPassword"` has exactly the same effect no matter if it's right after the `sudo` or right after the `bash`. It's sudo that decides that `su` is a separate command, and `su` that decides that `/bin/bash` is a separate command; the original shell doesn't know that.

Answer (score -1):

Your password does not end in a newline.
Try this

```
echo -n 'myPassword' | sudo -S su - userName -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: didn't work the solution.